# how to find distinct value in an array

Tags: c

I want to find similar values in an array. so if the value is not similar, the counter will increment by one. Code:

```
struct station{
    int d; //destination, one-way journey, no return
    int counter;
    int depart[10];
};
int main()
{
    int n = 0; //number of stations
    int k = 0; //k is how many route one station can go

    scanf("%d%d",&n, &k);

    //declare array of stations based on input, n.
    struct station list[n];

    //Initialization
    for(int i=0; i < n; i++){
        list[i].d = 0;
        list[i].counter = 0;
    }

    for(int i=0; i < n; i++){
        int to;
        scanf("%d", &to);
        list[i].d = to-1;
    }

   //this is where the problem is
    int ds = 0; //depart station 
    for(int ds=0; ds < n; ds++){ // n is number of station

        list[ds].depart[list[ds].counter] = ds;
        list[ds].counter = list[ds].counter + 1;

        int next = list[ds].d;
        for( int j = 0; j < k; j ++){ //k is how many route one station can go**

            list[ next ].depart[ list[ next ].counter ] = ds;

            if(list[ next ].depart[ list[ next ].counter ] != list[ next ].depart[ list[ next ].counter -1 ] ){
                list[ next ].counter = list[next].counter + 1;
            }
            next = list[next].d;
        }
    }

    for(int i=0; i < n; i++){
        printf("station [%d]: counter = %d: ", i+1 , list[i].counter);
        for(int j=0; j < list[ i ].counter; j++){
                if (list[i].depart[j] != list[i].depart[j-1] ){
                    printf("%d,", list[i].depart[j] );
            }
            }
        printf("\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Input:

```
5 3  
2  
3  
1  
4  
5
```

the input is enter in a way:
(number of station) (how many route one station can go)
(station 1 goes to)
(station 2 goes to)
(station 3 goes to)
(station 4 goes to)
(station 5 goes to)

This is my current output:

```
station [1]: counter = 3: 1,2,3  
station [2]: counter = 2: 2,3  
station [3]: counter = 2: 2,3  
station [4]: counter = 2: 4,5  
station [5]: counter = 2: 4,5
```

note: station 2 and 3 are supposed to display 1 in the output, not only 2 and 3.

I've tried this before:

```
    int ds = 0; //depart station 
    for(int ds=0; ds < n; ds++){ // n is number of station

        list[ds].depart[list[ds].counter] = ds;
        list[ds].counter = list[ds].counter + 1;

        int next = list[ds].d;
        for( int j = 0; j < k; j ++){ 

            list[ next ].depart[ list[ next ].counter ] = ds;
            list[ next ].counter = list[next].counter + 1;

            next = list[next].d;
        }
    }
```

The output will come out as below:

```
station [1]: counter = 4: 1,1,2,3  
station [2]: counter = 4: 1,2,2,3  
station [3]: counter = 4: 1,2,3,3  
station [4]: counter = 4: 4,4,5,5
station [5]: counter = 4: 4,4,5,5
```

Comment: Please show variable definitions. The code you presented generates no "output" - It doesn't have any `printf` or similar statements. Please show the code that generates the output. Please provide an [MCVE]

Comment: @KamilCuk i've made changes according to what you've said.